# I need my dropdown sub-sub-menu box to show sub-menu title above

Tags: menus

well I think the title says it all. 
I have 3 level menus, and I when I hover over 2 level menu, I want my 3 level menu to show it's parent page title(2 level menu item) in the dropdown box.

How do I go around this?

Comment: Quick answer: You need a [Walker](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) that supports this. To properly help you, we would need to know how you're currently displaying the menu.

Comment: hi Kero, I'm actually using wp_nav_menu with custom Walker (using it to add custom classes and IDs depending on depth of menu).